# How to get Response json data in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Below listed is my json response. My purpose is to get this data in javascript. My firebug console shows below result. Please help me to get data in js.

```
{"ProfessionFile":[[{"id":34,"title_en":"CEO"}],[{"id":35,"title_en":"PM"}]]}
```

Alert shows "undefined" result
**JS**

```
$(".tag-handler-ambition").ready(function () {
    $.get("/profession/file", {tagcategoryid: 3}, function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.ProfessionFile.length; i++) {
                alert(response.ProfessionFile[i].id);
                $(".tag-handler-ambition").after('<div id="filename-response_' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '"><a href="/profession/download/' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '">' + response.ProfessionFile[i].title_en + '.pdf</a></div>');
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should parse this response as a JSON, othewise JavaScript will not see it as an object:

```
$(".tag-handler-ambition").ready(function () {
    $.get("/profession/file", {tagcategoryid: 3}, function (response) {
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.ProfessionFile.length; i++) {
            $(".tag-handler-ambition").after('<div id="filename-response_' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '"><a href="/profession/download/' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '">' + response.ProfessionFile[i].title_en + '.pdf</a></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added this. But showing some error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data "       for (var i = 0; i < response.ProfessionFile.length; i++)
        {
            var obj = $.parseJSON( response.ProfessionFile[i].id );
            alert(obj);
        }

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your entire code. Can you take a look?

Comment: I have added your code but showing an error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data". For avoiding this I have added "response = JSON.stringify(response);" before parseJSON. Now alert showing  [undefined].

Comment: $(".tag-handler-ambition").ready(function () {
    $.get("/profession/file", {tagcategoryid: 3}, function (response) {
        response = JSON.stringify(response);
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.ProfessionFile.length; i++) {
            alert(response.ProfessionFile[i].id);
            $(".tag-handler-ambition").after('<div id="filename-response_' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '"><a href="/profession/download/' + response.ProfessionFile[i].id + '">' + response.ProfessionFile[i].title_en + '.pdf</a></div>');
        }
    });
});

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. Could you try $.getJSON? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/